# How to get typeahead hint working with angularjs bootstrap ui typeahead?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the angularjs-bootstrap-ui plugin found [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). Here  is my html

```
<input type="text" ng-model="asyncSelected" typeahead-loading="loadingPeople" typeahead-min-length="3" placeholder="Search People" typeahead="person for person in findPeople($viewValue)" class="form-control typeahead-input" />
```

This is working great, however it says that it is built off of the bootstrap api, and looking at [this](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) there should be a way to use "hint" as a parameter somehow so that when you type it shows a hint grayed out. Is this not in the angular bootstrap ui api at all?

Comment: I can't find anything updating the placeholder value here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/typeahead/typeahead.js

Answer (score 1):

To get Typeahead's hint functionality working with angular-ui's Typeahead directive simply add the `typeahead-show-hint="true"`attribute to the `input` element.
E.g:

```
<input
  type="text" 
  class="myClass"
  ng-model="selected" 
  uib-typeahead="item for item in vm.states | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8"
  placeholder="State"
  typeahead-show-hint="true"
/>
```